# Titanium Mapview Add Annotation

Tags: titanium

I 'm using the code 'http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132508/how-to-add-annotation-on-mapview-click-event' to calculate the lat and long.

But I getting some trouble in add a annotation.
The calculate result of long and lat is not correct so the point putted at wrong position
It's my problem or the method is not work now?

```
mapView.addEventListener('longpress', function(e) {
    var coordinate = calculateLatLngfromPixels(mapView, e.x, e.y);
    var longitude = coordinate.lon;
    var latitude = coordinate.lat;
    //var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
    //var latitude = e.coords.latitude;
    var annotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
                    latitude : latitude,
                    longitude : longitude,
                    title : "New Place",
                    //subtitle : 'My Place',
                    animate : true,
                    id : 1,
                    pincolor : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED
                });
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);

    var region = {
                    latitude : latitude,
                    longitude : longitude,
                    animate : true
                    //latitudeDelta : 0.002,
                    //longitudeDelta : 0.002
                };
    mapView.setLocation(region);
    alert('latitude'+latitude+' longitude'+longitude);
});
```

Thank you.

createMap:

```
var mapView = Ti.Map.createView({
     mapType: mapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
    //latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta:0.002  :  Zoom Level
    region : {
        latitude : curr_latitude,
        longitude : curr_longitude,
        latitudeDelta : 0.002,
        longitudeDelta : 0.002
    },
    top : 5,
    bottom : 5,
    left : 5,
    right : 5,
    animate : true,
    regionFit : true,
    userLocation : true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need difference between iOS and Android at listener and callback. I have created Mobile Project (Titanium SDK 3.3.0GA, Map 2.0.2 iOS | 2.1.4 Android)

ApplicationWindow.js

```
//Application Window Component Constructor
function ApplicationWindow() {

    //create component instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    });

    var calculateLatLngfromPixels = function(mapview, xPixels, yPixels) {
        var region = mapview.region;
        var heightDegPerPixel = -region.latitudeDelta / mapview.rect.height; 
        var widthDegPerPixel = region.longitudeDelta / mapview.rect.width;
        return {
            lat : (yPixels - mapview.rect.height / 2) * heightDegPerPixel + region.latitude,
            lon : (xPixels - mapview.rect.width / 2) * widthDegPerPixel + region.longitude
        };
    };

    var mapModule = require('ti.map');

    var mapView = mapModule.createView({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        mapType: mapModule.NORMAL_TYPE
    });

    var addNewAnnotation = function addNewAnnotation(lat, lng){
        Ti.API.info("New Annotation at: {"+lat+", "+lng+"}");
        var annotation = mapModule.createAnnotation({
            latitude : lat,
            longitude : lng,
            title : "New Place",
            animate : true,
            id : 1,
            pincolor : mapModule.ANNOTATION_RED
        });
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
    };

    if(Ti.Platform.osname === 'android'){
        mapView.addEventListener('longclick', function(e) {
            addNewAnnotation(e.latitude, e.longitude);  
        });
    }
    else {
        mapView.addEventListener('longpress', function(e) {
            var coordinates = calculateLatLngfromPixels(mapView, e.x, e.y);
            addNewAnnotation(coordinates.lat, coordinates.lon);  
        });
    }

    self.add(mapView);

    return self;
}

//make constructor function the public component interface
module.exports = ApplicationWindow;
```

I have compared two annotations on New York (Central Park and Apple Store) and the two coordinates are equals. This code works on iOS 7.1 and Android 4.4. More zoom, more accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it the different between Android and iOS?
I uploading the video...

Comment: Here is the result...  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kcyx5fo7q0cbm8/2014-08-20-18_38_14.mp4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think it's work but I got some trouble about the Google API(I think).   I added the code about how I create the Map.  Is it have problem?

Comment: I have not the problem showed at video. I think that the problem is GeoLocation (property userlocation or other parameter) also for create the map you must use [Map Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Map) not [API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Map) like my code due to is deprecated

Comment: Thank you... But I got another problem about insert the API key to the app.  I can't find the keystore in Titanium Folder. Also, I got error after insert the manifast (Invaild content)